# Edit inserted table sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When insert I need edit a value if it is null. I create a trigger but I don't know how to edit inserted table.

[image: Error]

```
ALTER TRIGGER [trigger1] on [dbo].[table]
instead of insert
as
    declare @secuencia bigint, @ID_PERSONA VARCHAR;

    select @secuencia = SECUENCIA from inserted 
    select @ID_PERSONA = ID_PERSONA from inserted 

    if @secuencia is null begin         
        set inserted.SECUENCIA = NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ_BIOINTEG --(Sequence)          
    end
```

Comment: Can you just use a default value on the table instead?

Comment: 2 things off the bat, `inserted` is a *virtual* table, you don't update it/set anything, you *join* it to your table on its primary key. What happens when more than a single row is inserted? See this [common trigger pitfall](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/)

Comment: What DBMS is this about? Please tag your request with it.

Comment: Looking at the linked image it appears to be SQL Server.

Comment: You really need to read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) which has multiple excellent examples on how to make use of the Inserted and Deleted pseudo-tables.

Comment: And are you sure you want a "instead of insert" why not an "after insert" and just update the column of interest, rather than handling the entire insert yourself.

Comment: And why add the sequence later? Why not add it as part of the original insert? Or in fact set it as a default value for the column? (as the first comment says).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i dont know how to edit inserted table.

You do not. That table is read only.

Note how your trigger also says:

> instead of insert

There is no way to edit the inserted table.

What you do instead, is setting up an INSERT command for the original table, using the data from the inserted table to filter to the ROWS of inserted - mostly by a join.

Changing inserted makes no sense, logically - because triggers in SQL are one of two things:

- INSTEAD OF - then there is no actual insert happening for inserted to start with. Instead of doing the insert, the trigger is called. As such, changing inserted - makes no sense.
- AFTER - then the insert already happened (and you UPDATE the rows). As the trigger runs after the update, changing inserting makes no sense.

Note that I say ROWS - your trigger has one very basic error: it assumes inerted contains ONE row. It is a table - it is possible the changes come from an insert statement that inserts multiple rows (which is trivial, i.e. select into, or simply an insert with values for multiple rows). Handle those.

> select @ID_PERSONA = ID_PERSONA from inserted

Makes NO sense - inserted is a table, so ID_PERSONA from inserted contains what value, if 2 rows are inserted? You must treat inserted like any other table.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from all the varied issues with your trigger code, as mentioned by others, the easiest way to use a `SEQUENCE` value in a table is to just put it in a `DEFAULT` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.[table]
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_table_seq
  DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.SEQ_BIOINTEG)
  FOR SECUENCIA;
```